# Perl fork process using open3

Tags: perl, fork, ipcopen3

I have a perl script in which I am forking a child process. Here is what I am doing:

```
my $pid = fork;

if($pid) {
# parent 
waitpid($pid, 0);
}
else {
exec("some other script X.pl");
}
```

Now, I wanted to capture the error of X.pl to display in my script. But as I understand this is not possible suing exec.

What are the other options I have?

How can I use open3 in my case?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of error will `X.pl` generate, will it exit with error code or it will display on the standard output?

Comment: It'll display it on STDOUT and will also return the exit code. I know how to capture the exit code, but I also want to get the error message.

Comment: both the `open` built-in and `open3` accept a dash as the command argument indicating that you actually want to fork instead of running an external program. Read the docs!

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is just the return value of X.pl you can use

```
my $returnValue = $?>>8;
```

See and http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html for more Information.
By the way, if all your parent does is wait for the child, using system is probably better than fork and exec by Hand.

edit:

To capture STDOUT you can use

```
my $output = qx/X.pl/;
```

instead of forking and exec. This will still alow you to inspect $? for the return values.
To not have perl interpolate the stuff in the command you can use also use `qx'command'` to pass the command to the System without changing anything.
If you want your parent to do stuff while waiting for X.pl but still want return value and Output of X.pl i would suggest looking into expect.
http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod

Comment: I used system call:
my $out = system("x.pl --command line args");
But the variable $out contains a numeric value.

Comment: Yes, the return value of System is the same value you can find in $?. Meaning rightshifting by 8 yields the return value of the started program. my $returnValue = (System ("X.pl")) >> 8;

Comment: Ya, but how do I get the string return Value?

Comment: String return value? If you want STDOUT use `qx/X.pl/` as i mentioned. If it is STDERR you are after, easiest is to still use qx// but Change Output. `$output = qx/X.pl 2>&1/;` gives you STDOUT and STDERR and `$output = qx"X.pl 2>&1 1>/dev/null";` gives you just STDERR while discarding STDOUT.

Comment: Thing is, my script, which is to come inside, qx// contains a lot of things. 
qx/"su - $user -c \"sudo x.pl -option 1 value1 -option2" \"/; and qx is not able to process this properly.

Comment: That is probably because qx// interpolates the string and tries to make sense of all the " and \ and $. If you use qx' ' instead, it should pass everything between the ' ' without changing anything to the System. Don't use " " in that case unless you would use them as well when inputting your command. If your command also has ' you Need to escape them by using \' but this is the only interpolating qx' ' does.

Comment: too late edit: Be sure to use ' and not backticks (in fact qx// is just a fancy way of using `` and better because you can use qx'' ) ^^

Comment: So with qx'' no interpolation of the command is done. 
What if my command has 1-2 variables that I do want to get interpolated?

Comment: Then either use `qx//` and escape (put a backslash in front) any Special caracters you want to pass on or use something like `my $command = 'Stuff not to be interpolated ', $perlvariable ,' more literal stuff'; qx/$command/;` and use the fact that `qx//` interpolates only once and thereby passes the string in `$command` as it is in there.